# SQL Server - converting 13 digit numeric to datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I convert a 13 digit numeric like 1314637182953 to `datetime` in SQL Server? Both casting and converting directly give an arithmetic overflow error!

Same result with the query below:

```
select Convert(datetime, cast(START_DATE as varchar(8)), 112), * 
from table
```

Comment: What does the number represent?

Comment: It column definition is numeric with length 9 and precision 19, but as the name (START_DATE) suggests, it contains a date. All the values in this column are 13 digit numbers and I need to get the actual date from them.

Comment: Do you know what date the example you have given should translate to?

Comment: I am not sure of the exact date it should translate to, but the answer below seems to be converting it and the converted dates seem to be OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming it's [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds, try this:

```
DATEADD(SECOND, START_DATE/1000 ,'1970/1/1')
```

For the number from your post, SQL-2008 returns `2011-08-29 16:59:42.000`

Comment: And if you want to convert the timestamp to date in JS, use `new Date(START_DATE * 1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

We are far enough past the epoch (1/1/1970) that you may get an overflow error with the above code.
It can be fixed easily by casting the field in question as a BIGINT data type before dividing by 1000 as below:

```
DATEADD(SECOND, CAST(START_DATE as BIGINT)/1000 ,'1970/1/1')
```

Comment: It seems the CAST is not necessary (anymore?).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to chop off the miliseconds:

```
CAST(DATEADD(ms, CAST(RIGHT(START_DATE,3) AS smallint), DATEADD(s, START_DATE / 1000, '1970-01-01')) AS datetime2(3))
```