# How to convert 13 digit timestamp to date and time format in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to store 13 digit timestamp to store date time format in MS SQL table.
I have tried in many ways and also searched in SO posts nothing is helped for me.

**Input Code :** `1525939481255`

**Required Format** : `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS (12 hour time format)`

I want to convert the above 13 digit code to the above mentioned format.
Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: What output you need from the input you have given?

Comment: @PawanKumar convert that 13 digit code to above mentioned time and date format

Comment: try this and feedback me: `select dateadd(second, 1525939481255/1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101')`

Comment: @HasanFathi got the return like as 2018-05-10 16:04:41.000

Comment: @HasanFathi But I need to convert as 12 hour time format as I mentioned above .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - converting 13 digit numeric to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539204/sql-server-converting-13-digit-numeric-to-datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assuming that was unix time in miliseconds
so try this query

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(SECOND, 1525939481255/1000 ,'1970/1/1'),105)
```

I'm sorry, i miss the time format,

Try this one..

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(SECOND, 1525939481255/1000 ,'1970/1/1'),105) + ' ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, 1525939481255/1000 ,'1970/1/1'),'h:mm:ss tt')
```

CMIIW,
please let me know, if this help..

Comment: it returns the date as I expected but Time is missing (10-05-2018)

Comment: I have found a another one error here ,There is 5:50 hours difference between the 13 digit code (time ) compare with the local time

Comment: Is it a fault from 13 digit code or can we convert it in sql

Comment: No validations it is a raw code generated from angular4 application

Comment: can u provide the 13 digit code? and what it supposed to be in date time?

Comment: I mean the 13 digit timestamp which I have given in my post

Comment: I think utc + 5.30 convertion is needed for getting the actual time from the 13 digit timestamp

Comment: Here my actual time is 2:40:12 PM ,But from my application (convertion of 13 digit code)I got the time as 9:01:12 AM ,SO there is 5:30 hr difference .How to solve this

Comment: `SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, 1525939481255/1000 ,'1970/1/1'), 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM:ss')` is more simplest way with `FORMAT`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare varchar(max) myDateTime = select dateadd(second, 1525939481255/1000 + 8*60*60, '19700101');

SELECT  REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                RIGHT(
                    '0000000000' + 
                        CONVERT(
                        varchar(10), 
                        cast(myDateTime as time(0)), 
                        109),
                10), 
            'PM', 
            ' p.m.'),
        'AM',
        ' a.m.') as 'Time'
 , reverse(Left(myDateTime, 10)) as 'date'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [UNIX time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539265/4910880) can be convert to normal datetime and will be format to your expected format as:

```
DECLARE @DateValue AS BIGINT = 1525939481255;

SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(SECOND, @DateValue/1000 ,'1970/1/1'), 105) + ' ' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, @DateValue/1000 ,'1970/1/1') AS TIME), 100)
```

output:

```
10-05-2018 8:04AM
```